# ImageMagick treating JPG and GIF differently in -alpha shape

Tags: imagemagick, png, jpeg, gif, imagemagick-convert

I just encountered unexpected behavior in ImageMagick, which I'm hoping someone can explain to me.

**Version numbers**

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2013-02-25 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Running on Linux Mint 15 Olivia (based on Ubuntu 13.04 "Raring Ringtail").

**Executive summary**

Running the same operation with two images that should be quite similar, except that one is a GIF while the other is a JPEG, the resulting output is entirely different. The GIF comes out black, the JPEG comes out white.

**To reproduce:**

- Go to http://karenswhimsy.com/public-domain-images/animal-silhouettes/animal-silhouettes-1.shtm and download the elephant silhouette as `elephant.jpg`
- Download http://www.arthursclipart.org/silhouettes/animals/DUCK1.gif as `DUCK1.gif`
- `convert elephant.jpg -negate -alpha shape output-elephant.png`
- `convert DUCK1.gif -negate -alpha shape output-duck.png`
- Compare the `output-elephant.png` and `output-duck.png` images

Can anyone explain why these two output images are different? Why the GIF duck ends up being black after conversion, while the JPEG elephant becomes white after conversion?

**Long-winded explanation**

The situation is this: I want to take some black-and-white images, turn the background transparent, and turn the foreground different colors. For example, starting with the elephant silhouette at http://karenswhimsy.com/public-domain-images/animal-silhouettes/images/animal-silhouettes-1.jpg (I saved the image as `elephant.jpg`), I want to produce a .png with a transparent background and an elephant that's green, red, yellow, or whatever color I want.

The command I'm using to do this is:

```
convert elephant.jpg -negate -alpha shape +level-colors ,green green-elephant.png
```

This does exactly what I want. First it inverts the image so that the background is black and the elephant is white, because `-alpha shape` expects an alpha mask where black = fully transparent and white = fully opaque. Then `-alpha shape` does its magic and produces a white elephant against a transparent background. Then `+level-colors ,green` kicks in, transforming black-and-white gradients into the two colors specified as parameters to `+level-colors`; here, the first color is omitted so it would remain black, and the second color is what white turns into. This produces a green elephant with smooth borders -- exactly the result I want -- and I'm quite happy with it.

Next, I tried running the same command against one of the images from http://www.arthursclipart.org/silhouettes/animals.htm (I used `DUCK1.gif`). The input source is the same -- a black silhouette against a white background -- so I expected the same result, a green duck against a transparent background. But it didn't work. A little research showed me that `-alpha shape` was behaving differently. Where with the JPEG elephant it was producing a white elephant against a transparent background, with the GIF duck the same command was producing a black duck against a transparent background. In other words, `-alpha shape` was inverting the result with a GIF image source, but not with a JPEG image source. So to color the animal properly, I needed to rewrite the `+level-colors` parameters to put "green" *before* the comma instead of *after*.

Tweaking my script is no problem at all, but I'd love to understand **why** this is happening, and so far I'm clueless. Can anyone explain to me why ImageMagick is treating GIFs and JPEGs so differently in the `-alpha shape` operation?

Comment: "You don't have permission to access /public-domain-images/animal-silhouettes/images/animal-silhouettes-1.jpg on this server."

Comment: Huh. I guess her server checks referer URLs. Try http://karenswhimsy.com/public-domain-images/animal-silhouettes/animal-silhouettes-1.shtm -- that should work, and I'll update my post with that URL instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think here is the story. With GIF, a background color might be explicitly defined, and I think that is the case with DUCK1.GIF. Not so with JPEG; here the background is, I think, assumed to be "white".

Whatever the case is, converting the DUCK1.GIF to DUCK1.JPG results in a similar image to the elephant. Moreover, you can make sure that the same background color is used with the apropriate Imagemagick option. The two commands below produce similar output:

```
convert DUCK1.jpg -background Black -negate -alpha shape output-duck.png
convert elephant.jpg -background Black -negate -alpha shape output-elephant.png
```

Comment: That was it. I looked up the GIF spec then checked the file with a hex editor, and `DUCK1.gif` had the background color explicitly set to black. I coped it to `DUCK2.gif`, changed the background color to white in the hex editor while touching no other bytes, and it started behaving exactly like `elephant.jpg` in my ImageMagick pipeline. Thanks for figuring it out; I was really scratching my head over this one.